# Why is the colored ribbon repeated multiple times in the output

Tags: c, ncurses

The code in main prints a colored ribbon before the while and when I try to repeat this process inside the while after the user enters a 1, the constant adjusts the possible wavelengths (that are four) within the visible and assigns a character to the specified position of the array based on the o shape's wavelength, otherwise prints empty space for other colors.

[image: Result:]

It happens that after the user informs 1, the tape is repeated 3 more times after the first one, as in the print of the result above, only a ribbon should be printed. What makes it happen?
compile `-lncursesw` environment `xfce4-terminal`
I think it's because of the `wprintw(stdscr, "%lc", randomCharacter);`, I noticed that each new strip contains the `randomCharacter` drawn in a different position corresponding to one of the four possible lengths of the `adjustedConstant`, so this totals 4 strips instead of one.
`i == index` it is a way of visualizing the colors associated with specific wavelengths within the visible light spectrum.
When the user enters a value other than -1, the program calculates the wavelength associated with the given input using the formula given by `adjustedConstant`. If that wavelength is within the visible range (between 400 nm and 700 nm), the program determines the corresponding position in the array of colors (colors) and prints a random character with the color associated with that wavelength.
When pressed 1 ->

```
1n = 2, 2n = 3, Wavelength: 6.564696e-07 meters
1n = 2, 2n = 4, Wavelength: 4.862738e-07 meters
1n=2, 2n=5, Wavelength: 4.341730e-07 meters
1n=2, 2n=6, Wavelength: 4.102935e-07 meters
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curses.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct {
  int r;
  int g;
  int b;
} RGB;

RGB newRGB(int r, int g, int b) {
  RGB color;
  color.r = r;
  color.g = g;
  color.b = b;
  return color;
}

void calculateColor(RGB *colors, int totalColors, int currentIndex, float saturation, float luminosity);
double adjustedConstant() {
  return 1.0973731568508E7 / (1 + 9.10938356E-31 / 1.67262192E-27);
}

int main() {
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

  int totalColors = 60;
  RGB colors[totalColors];
  float saturation = 1.0;
  float luminosity = 0.3;

  initscr();
  start_color();

  int end = totalColors - 18;
  int start = end - 42;
  for (int i = end; i >= start; i--) {
    calculateColor(&colors[i], totalColors, i, saturation, luminosity);

    // Convert RGB colors to curses default model
    int r = colors[i].r * 1000 / 255;
    int g = colors[i].g * 1000 / 255;
    int b = colors[i].b * 1000 / 255;

    // Set color in curses
    init_color(i + 16, r, g, b); // needs to define the pair of colors i+16
    init_pair(i + 16, COLOR_BLACK, i + 16);

    // Print the color
    attron(COLOR_PAIR(i + 16)); // needs to activate the pair of colors i+16
    printw("  ");
    attroff(COLOR_PAIR(i + 16));
  }

  // Vector of characters for drawing
  int characters[] = {
    9474, 9475, 10072, 10073, 12321
  };
  int numCharacters = sizeof(characters) / sizeof(characters[0]);

  // Loop to print the colors on the screen
  int wavelength;
  while (1) {
    int number;
    printw("\n\nEnter 1 or -1 to exit: ");
    scanw("%d", &number);

    if (number == -1) {
      break; // Exit the loop if the user enters -1
    }

    // Wavelength
    int n1 = 1, n2 = 2;
    double lambda_a = 0;

    while (1) {
      lambda_a = 1.0 / (adjustedConstant() * ((1.0 / (n1 * n1)) - (1.0 / (n2 * n2))));

      if (lambda_a >= 400E-9 && lambda_a <= 700E-9) {

        // Calculate the position in the colors array based on the wavelength
        int index = (700 - lambda_a * 1e9) * (totalColors - 10.5) / (750 - 380);
        // Print all colors
        for (int i = end; i >= start; i--) {
          if (i == index) {
            // Activate the color pair for the corresponding wavelength color
            attron(COLOR_PAIR(i + 16));
            // Draw one of the characters randomly
            int randomCharacter = characters[rand() % numCharacters];
            wprintw(stdscr, "%lc", randomCharacter);
            // Deactivate the color pair
            attroff(COLOR_PAIR(i + 16));
          } else {
            // Draw empty spaces for the other colors
            attron(COLOR_PAIR(i + 16));
            printw("  ");
            attroff(COLOR_PAIR(i + 16));
          }
        }
        refresh(); // Update the screen
      }
      if (lambda_a > 700E-9) {
        break; // Wavelength exceeded the visible range, end the loop
      }
      n2++; // Increment the value of 2n
      if (n2 <= 6) {
        continue;
      }
      n1++; // Increment the value of 1n and reset 2n to a value greater than 1n
      n2 = n1 + 1;
    }
  }
  getch(); // Wait for user input
  endwin(); // End curses mode
  return 0;
}

void calculateColor(RGB *colors, int totalColors, int currentIndex, float saturation, float luminosity) {
  float hue = currentIndex * (360.0 / totalColors);
  float chroma = (1 - fabs(2 * luminosity - 1)) * saturation;
  float x = chroma * (1 - fabs(fmod(hue / 60, 2) - 1));
  float m = luminosity - chroma / 2;

  float r, g, b;
  if (hue >= 0 && hue < 60) {
    r = chroma;
    g = x;
    b = 0;
  } else if (hue >= 60 && hue < 120) {
    r = x;
    g = chroma;
    b = 0;
  } else if (hue >= 120 && hue < 180) {
    r = 0;
    g = chroma;
    b = x;
  } else if (hue >= 180 && hue < 240) {
    r = 0;
    g = x;
    b = chroma;
  } else if (hue >= 240 && hue < 300) {
    r = x;
    g = 0;
    b = chroma;
  } else {
    r = chroma;
    g = 0;
    b = x;
  }
  colors->r = (r + m) * 255;
  colors->g = (g + m) * 255;
  colors->b = (b + m) * 255;
}
```

Comment: Could you make a more [mre], which only demonstrates the unexpected output in realtion to user input?

Comment: @Yunnosch I already reduced as much as possible, what else can be reduced is, ..., if I remove that `attron` and `attroff` inside `for (int i = end; i >= start; i--) {`, which prints the first fixed tape as an example, contained before the user informs the value

Comment: It repeats until `lambda_a > 700E-9`. What is it supposed to do instead?

Comment: @Barmar the inner loop continues as long as `lambda <= 700E-9`, once `lambda_a` reaches this value it will continue printing the color ribbon indefinitely.
For that, I added a check condition right after the calculation of `lambda_a` inside the inner loop. If `lambda_a` is outside the visible range, use the `break` statement to exit the inner loop and continue with the outer loop to receive the next user input.
`if (lambda_a > 700E-9) {
      break; 
    }`

Comment: I know, that's exactly what I said. It takes 4 iterations before the `lambda_a` condition is reached, so you get 4 ribbons.

Comment: Why isn't that the expected result?

Comment: It's your program, why don't you know? What is all that `lambda_a` stuff supposed to mean?

Comment: @Barmar I really don't know 
But I think it's because of the `wprintw(stdscr, "%lc", randomCharacter);`, I noticed that each new strip contains the `randomCharacter` drawn in a different position corresponding to one of the four possible lengths of the `adjustedConstant`, so this totals 4 strips instead on one.

Comment: Why do you think that's related? You get 4 strips because the loop executes 4 times. Try printing the value of `lambda_a` in the loop, is it what you expect? If not, examine the code that updates it and fix it to do what you want.

Comment: Why do you even have a loop if it's not supposed to print multiple strips.

Comment: @Barmar The loop prints four times because there are 4 characters drawn. I still don't know if I understand how to print the 4 characters drawn on a single tape.

Comment: There are 2 loops: `while(1)` that loops until the `lambda_a` condition is met, and `for (int i = end; i >= start; i--)` that prints each character. I thought the inner loop prints one ribbon, and the outer loop makes multiple ribbons.

Comment: @Barmar exactly the for loop `for (int i = end; i >= start; i--)` outside the while prints a fixed colored ribbon before the user reports any value. In the while loop it should print the same tape with the `randomCharacter` in the position calculated by the `adjustedConstant`

Comment: I don't understand what the `randomCharacter` is supposed to look like.

Comment: @Barmar are the characters that will be chosen 0x2502 - │ = 9474,
0x2503 - ┃ = 9475, 0x2758 - ❘ = 10072, 0x2759 - ❙ = 10073, 0x3021 - 〡= 12321

Comment: Your outer loop executes several times and prints a spectrum whenever `lambda_a` is between 400E-9 and 700e-9. But this condition occurs four times. I find that `lambda_a` passes through: 656.47E-9, 486.274E-9, 434.173E-9, 410.294E-9. You need to rethink program logic. What are you trying to achieve with printing a random character when `i == index`?

Comment: I'm going to have to leave this discussion. I don't understand enough about how ncurses prints those characters and colors.

Comment: @adabsurdum I had to edit my question to respond to your comment. Because mine was too long. please look there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop logic in the posted code is incorrect.

OP code has an outer loop that calculates `lambda_a` values which presumably correspond with spectral absorption lines, and an inner loop that prints a color spectrum, either as blocks or as characters depending on the color index associated with the `lambda_a` value. The inner loop prints a color spectrum and checks for a match with the index associated with `lambda_a`, printing a character in that case, and then `lambda_a` is modified in the outer loop. By this process, four values of `lambda_a` appear in the visible spectrum range (`lambda_a >= 400E-9 && lambda_a <= 700E-9`) so the spectrum is printed four times.

A better approach would be to calculate and cache color indexes which match an absorption line. Then when the color spectrum is printed once, if the color index matches a cached index a character is printed.

Here is a modified version of OP code that implements this. There is now a loop which populates `line_idxs` with color indexes for absorption lines based on original OP code. A loop which prints a spectrum follows. Note that this code steps through `line_idxs` in reverse because the printing order of colors is from highest index to lowest while the absorption lines were found in lowest to highest order.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curses.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct {
    int r;
    int g;
    int b;
} RGB;

RGB newRGB(int r, int g, int b) {
    RGB color;
    color.r = r;
    color.g = g;
    color.b = b;
    return color;
}

void calculateColor(RGB *colors, int totalColors, int currentIndex, float saturation, float luminosity);
double adjustedConstant() {
    return 1.0973731568508E7 / (1 + 9.10938356E-31 / 1.67262192E-27);
}

int main(void) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    int totalColors = 60;
    RGB colors[totalColors];
    float saturation = 1.0;
    float luminosity = 0.3;

    initscr();
    start_color();

    int end = totalColors - 18;
    int start = end - 42;
    for (int i = end; i >= start; i--) {
        calculateColor(&colors[i], totalColors, i, saturation, luminosity);

        // Convert RGB colors to curses default model
        int r = colors[i].r * 1000 / 255;
        int g = colors[i].g * 1000 / 255;
        int b = colors[i].b * 1000 / 255;

        // Set color in curses
        init_color(i + 16, r, g, b); // needs to define the pair of colors i+16
        init_pair(i + 16, COLOR_BLACK, i + 16);

        // Print the color
        attron(COLOR_PAIR(i + 16)); // needs to activate the pair of colors i+16
        printw("  ");
        attroff(COLOR_PAIR(i + 16));
    }

    // Vector of characters for drawing
    int characters[] = {
        9474, 12321
    };
    int numCharacters = sizeof(characters) / sizeof(characters[0]);

    // Loop to print the colors on the screen
    // int wavelength;
    while (1) {
        int number;
        printw("\n\nEnter 1 or -1 to exit: ");
        scanw("%d", &number);

        if (number == -1) {
            break; // Exit the loop if the user enters -1
        }

        // Wavelength
        int n1 = 1, n2 = 2;
        int line_idxs[4] = { 0 };  // Save spectral line indices.

        // Populate `line_idxs[]` with spectral lines.
        for(size_t i = 0; i < 4;) {
            double lambda_a = 0;
            lambda_a =(1.0 / (adjustedConstant() * ((1.0 / (n1 * n1)) - (1.0 / (n2 * n2)))));
            if (lambda_a >= 400E-9 && lambda_a <= 700E-9) {
                line_idxs[i] = start + (700 - lambda_a * 1e9) * (totalColors - 10.5) / (750 - 380);
                i++;
            }
            n2++;
            if (n2 <= 6) continue;
            n1++;
            n2 = n1 + 1;
        }

        // Print spectrum.
        for (int i = end, line_idx = 3; i >= start; i--) {
            attron(COLOR_PAIR(i + 16));
            if (line_idx >= 0 && i == line_idxs[line_idx]) {
                // Print a random character.
                int randomCharacter = characters[rand() % numCharacters];
                wprintw(stdscr, "%lc", randomCharacter);
                --line_idx;
            } else {
                printw("  ");
            }
            attroff(COLOR_PAIR(i + 16));
        }
        refresh(); // Update the screen
    }
    getch(); // Wait for user input
    endwin(); // End curses mode

    return 0;
}

void calculateColor(RGB *colors, int totalColors, int currentIndex, float saturation, float luminosity) {
    float hue = currentIndex * (360.0 / totalColors);
    float chroma = (1 - fabs(2 * luminosity - 1)) * saturation;
    float x = chroma * (1 - fabs(fmod(hue / 60, 2) - 1));
    float m = luminosity - chroma / 2;

    float r, g, b;
    if (hue >= 0 && hue < 60) {
        r = chroma;
        g = x;
        b = 0;
    } else if (hue >= 60 && hue < 120) {
        r = x;
        g = chroma;
        b = 0;
    } else if (hue >= 120 && hue < 180) {
        r = 0;
        g = chroma;
        b = x;
    } else if (hue >= 180 && hue < 240) {
        r = 0;
        g = x;
        b = chroma;
    } else if (hue >= 240 && hue < 300) {
        r = x;
        g = 0;
        b = chroma;
    } else {
        r = chroma;
        g = 0;
        b = x;
    }
    colors->r = (r + m) * 255;
    colors->g = (g + m) * 255;
    colors->b = (b + m) * 255;
}
```

Here is the resulting display:

[image]

Note that the length of the second color spectrum is shorter than the first and the color blocks in the second spectrum are not aligned with the color blocks in the first. This is because the printed representation of the taller bar is narrower than the printed representation of the shorter bar. You can fix this by switching on `randomCharacter` and printing an extra space for narrower characters. Here I have added some `#define`s to make working with character codes easier. The `switch` statement is used so that further characters may be easily introduced by adding additional cases:

```
/* ... */

#define TALLBAR   9474
#define SHORTBAR  12321

/* ... */

    int characters[] = { TALLBAR, SHORTBAR };

/* ... */

        // Print spectrum.
        for (int i = end, line_idx = 3; i >= start; i--) {
            attron(COLOR_PAIR(i + 16));
            if (line_idx >= 0 && i == line_idxs[line_idx]) {
                // Print a random character.
                int randomCharacter = characters[rand() % numCharacters];
                switch (randomCharacter) {
                case TALLBAR:
                    wprintw(stdscr, "%lc ", randomCharacter);
                    break;
                default:
                    wprintw(stdscr, "%lc", randomCharacter);
                }
                --line_idx;
            } else {
                printw("  ");
            }
            attroff(COLOR_PAIR(i + 16));
        }

/* ... */
```

Of course, many further refinements are possible. Here is the resulting display after printing several spectra using the modified program:

[image]

Comment: thanks, could you tell me why in `// Print spectrum. for (int i = end, line_idx = 3; i >= start; i--)` line_idx = 3;?

Comment: @AxionIons -- `line_idxs` holds color indexes: [0] = 5 (656nm), [1] = 28 (486nm), [2] = 35 (434nm), and [3] = 38 (410nm). The order is a result of the way `lambda_a` is updated and the fact that I filled `line_idxs` starting from 0. `line_idx` is the index into `line_idxs` that is being tested against for printing a character. Since your original code printed color indexes from `end` to `start` the `i` in the printing loop it needs to start from the highest color index in `line_idxs`, which is when `line_idx` is 3.

Comment: If `line_idx` started from 0 and incremented then `i` would start (from `end`) by testing against the lowest color index (5); after this is matched `i` would continue decreasing (towards `start`) and  could no longer match 28, 35, or 38. In that case only one line would be printed (the line for color index 5).

Comment: I made an array for the user to inform between 1 and 57. And I made a `calculateQuantityVisibleResults` function to print before `int line_idxs[4] = { 0 };` and saves the amount of spectral line indices. I thought this would help position other slashes by `R` as possible. But, for example: when it `informs 57` instead of being printed `6 bars` as in the [result R](https://i.imgur.com/s4rWpWA.jpg). I only get `1`.
I also changed the `AdjustConstant to (double Rinf, double me, double M);` [font pastebin](https://pastebin.com/WYPzB2zU);

Comment: @AxionIons -- it looks like `line_idxs` contains indexes in different orders depending on user input; I'm not sure why this is at the moment. You can sort the indexes into ascending order, which is what the printing code expects while searching for spectral line indices. Just add `qsort(line_idxs, resultadosValidos, sizeof *line_idxs, ascending_int);` before the loop that prints the color spectrum so that `line_idxs` is sorted. You will also need to define a comparison function `ascending_int` before `main`. I tested this and it seemed to work.

Comment: `int ascending_int(const void *int_a, const void *int_b) {
    int a = *(int *)int_a;
    int b = *(int *)int_b;
    return (a > b) - (a < b);
}`

Comment: [update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76879479/sync-flashing-display)

Answer (score 0):

The ribbon is printed multiple times because the condition of the outer loop stays true for 4 iterations.

You should output a `'\n'` after the ribbon loop so all ribbons appear aligned instead vertically instead of a long wrapping ribbon.